# Return either binding data or recycler view problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

Inside my fragment, i have some image and views that are getting their values by binding data, and beneath them a RecyclerView. The images and textviews are showing successfully but my Recyclerview won't show. If i return my view only, the RecyclerView shows but the binded data doesn't. I want to view both of them.

[[image]]

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment(), LessonRecyclerAdapter.LessonItemListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.lessonRecyclerView)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host )

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.lessonData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val adapter =
                LessonRecyclerAdapter(
                    it,
                    this
                )
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        })

        // return binding data
        val binding = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        return binding.root
        //return view
    }
```

Comment: can you please modify question with xml of your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, There are two inflates, one for binding and another for view(for recyclerview setup). The easy solution is to directly use `recyclerview` from binding variable to set up the list as:

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentDetailBinding

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host )

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)

        binding = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        viewModel.lessonData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val adapter =
                LessonRecyclerAdapter(
                    it,
                    this
                )
            // directly access the view using ids                
            binding.lessonRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        })

        return binding.root
    }
```

Another option is to [use binding adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic) with live data to setup adapter and pass the data to the adapter.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a treat. I did have to move the viewmodel intilization above the binding code, but it worked superbly.

Comment: I am glad that I could help, missed the viewmodel use as I used the notepad :) though happy coding! you can create a method in the adapter to receive new data(use `notifydatasetchanged` to refresh) to avoid creating a new adapter object for new data.